# Good web application for idea proposal/voting/commenting?

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm searching for a web application that will allow members of my team to propose ideas and those ideas to be discussed in comments (if nested, that would rock) and ideas to be voted for the most fruitful ones to come up to the top.

I've seen another question with an answer on Google Moderator, but that does not seem to leave much place for commenting.

My options so far:

- [UserVoice](http://uservoice.com/) seems like a nice option (although a little expensive IMO).
- [Tricider](http://tricider.com) (is it possible to have private communities?)
- WordPress with a vote plugin (I'm sure there's one out there, any recommendations?)

So, for short: **what would you recommend for a private voting/feedback/commenting application?**

Comment: You may should give https://pollunit.com a try. This is a poll maker with good commenting features like nesting and reactions and. There is also a idea collection poll type.

Answer (score 0):

Could be done easily with Drupal and [Vote Up/Down](http://drupal.org/project/vote_up_down) module. [Drupal 6.22](http://drupal.org/project/drupal) will be good for this. Allow your team members to post articles and enable voting. I would also install [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) and replaced home page with a view that sorts by number of votes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest Trello.

I think you have to move voted cards to the to of the lists manually.

- Privacy, you can invite who you want
- Voting built in, but up votes only, and not anonymous
- No nesting, I.e. threading of comments, they just appear as a list on thee card.

It's pretty slick, free, fast and well worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you like the Stack Exchange network you might find one of the "clones" a good way to go. One advantage is you can self-host and probably customize the app a little more. See [this meta SO question for some options](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones).